# Add two numbers instead of combining

Tags: java, algorithm, math, ide, multiplication

I am trying to create a program in which a user can enter 2 numbers and the program will take the 2 numbers and multiply them to get an answer. However, for this specific example, I am simply trying to take 2 numbers from a user and I want Java to add them. eg `1+1=2`, instead of `1+1=11`.

My code:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class MultiplicationTables {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        //declare variables

        String num1;
        String num2;
        int ans=0;

        num1=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter a number");
        num2=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter another number");

        ans=Integer.parseInt(num1);
        ans=Integer.parseInt(num2);


        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Your answer is " + (num1+num2));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using `num1` and `num2` which are Strings instead of `ans` which should be your sum as an `int`.
Also you don't add correctly the 2 values into `ans`.

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    String num1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter a number");
    String num2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter another number");

    int ans = Integer.parseInt(num1);
    ans += Integer.parseInt(num2);

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Your answer is " + ans);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

`num1` and `num2` are `String`.
 
So as you write `num1+num2` you get the result of their concatenation.

In fact, you don't use the `Integer.parseInt();` results.

Instead, do it to addition two `int` values:

```
int result = Integer.parseInt(num1) + Integer.parseInt(num2);
```

And display `result` :

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Your answer is " + result);
```

Comment: This time you beat me, although you came in one minute later ;-)

Comment: I waited almost a minute figuring out weather this question is worth answering and there you go, 5 up votes :p

Comment: @AniketSahrawat The answers are fine (maybe biased here), the question is close to "too basic" ;-)

Comment: @Aniket Sahrawat, I also hesitated. Sincerely, I have still hard time to guess whether the question should be answered or commented

Answer (score 6):

Here:

```
num1=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter a number");
num2=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter another number");
```

The option pane returns strings, what you seem to understand, as you then go:

```
ans=Integer.parseInt(num1);
ans=Integer.parseInt(num2);
```

But then you use the `+` operator on your **string** results:

```
... +(num1+num2));
```

But `+` for strings **concatenates** them.

So instead of "adding" strings, you want to add the **numbers**, as in:

```
int1FromUser = Integer.parseInt(num1);
int2FromUser = Integer.parseInt(num2);

int sum = int1FromUser + int2FromUser;
```

That is all there is to this.

( and I took the freedom to use slightly better naming - keep in mind to use variable names that **say** something about the meaning of the thing they point to )

Answer (score 3):

`+` is used in addition when using `Integer` or `int`, and it also used to  concatenate two `String`s. In your case `num1` and `num2` are `String`s, and hence it is concatenating the result. So you will have to change your code to reflect following changes:

```
ans = Integer.parseInt(num1);
ans += Integer.parseInt(num2); // add the result of parseInt to ans
//--^---------------------------
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Your answer is " + ans ); // another one
```

Or alternatively:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Your answer is " + (Integer.parseInt(num1) + Integer.parseInt(num2)));
```

Answer (score 3):

You are doing it wrong. You are adding Strings in the end and ignoring the parsed Integers.

And also you using the same integer variable for both inputs.

So that should be

```
int ans1=0;
int ans2=0;

...

 ans1=Integer.parseInt(num1);
 ans2=Integer.parseInt(num2);
```

And in the end

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Your answer is " +(ans1+ans2));
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you change the last line of your method to:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Your answer is " + (Integer.parseInt(num1) + Integer.parseInt(num2)));
```

This way, you don't need the "ans" variable (which in your code doesn't really do anything) at all. Instead, you can simply parse the int values and add them on the same line as you're writing the message.

If you want to use ans, try this:

```
ans = Integer.parseInt(num1) + Integer.parseInt(num2);
```

Then:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Your answer is " + ans);
```

Comment: This is the best answer I got from this question. Your method makes complete sense to me and I can understand it very well considering I am a borderline beginner in writing Java. Thank you @basillicum